# Where is #this.datasource# usually defined?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a test site and a live site on ColdFusion 9. I'm trying to push the 'html' and 'components' folders from the test site to the live site. For some reason the live site now feeds off of the test data/content. I'm assuming that this is related to the datasource (#this.datasource# or #Application.datasource#). Where is this usually defined? I'm hoping that I can find this and then get the datasource to point to the old/live content and not the test content.

I just want to move the new CODE and keep the old DATA...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking in a file named Application.cfc. This would most likely be in the root of the application, but sub-folders may also have Application.cfc in them.

Comment: if that fails, use a search tool [like grep] to find "this.datasource"